# UrlEncode in dotnet-core with TextEncoding

Tags: c#

I have a text that retrieved from the web and saved into a file with encoding 1252.

Text has URL's in it with some emoji's. However unless I get the result from **method1** below, I can not be able to retrieve those pages.

Since we don't have **System.Web** in [dotnet-core](/questions/tagged/dotnet-core) and no support from **System.Net.WebUtility** for **TextEncoding**, I wonder, if there is an easy way to handle this issue?

```
var text = $"hello-world ðŸ–¤ðŸ’--œðŸ’œðŸ–";

Encoding sourceEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

// method 1 // hello-world+%f0%9f%96%a4%f0%9f%92--%9c%f0%9f%92%9c%f0%9f%96 // <----- result, I would like to get
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text, sourceEncoding).Dump();

// method 2 // hello-world+%c3%b0%c5%b8%e2%80%93%c2%a4%c3%b0%c5%b8%e2%80%99--%c5%93%c3%b0%c5%b8%e2%80%99%c5%93%c3%b0%c5%b8%e2%80%93
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text).Dump();

// method 3 // hello-world+%C3%B0%C5%B8%E2%80%93%C2%A4%C3%B0%C5%B8%E2%80%99--%C5%93%C3%B0%C5%B8%E2%80%99%C5%93%C3%B0%C5%B8%E2%80%93
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(text).Dump();

// method 4 // hello-world%20%C3%B0%C5%B8%E2%80%93%C2%A4%C3%B0%C5%B8%E2%80%99--%C5%93%C3%B0%C5%B8%E2%80%99%C5%93%C3%B0%C5%B8%E2%80%93
System.Uri.EscapeUriString(text).Dump();

// method5 // hello-world%20%F0%9F%96%A4%EF%BF%BD--%EF%BF%BD%F0%9F%92%9C%EF%BF%BD
System.Uri.EscapeUriString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sourceEncoding.GetBytes(text))).Dump();

// method6 // hello-world+%F0%9F%96%A4%EF%BF%BD--%EF%BF%BD%F0%9F%92%9C%EF%BF%BD
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sourceEncoding.GetBytes(text))).Dump();
```

Comment: Maybe? `var url = "http://example.com/" + string.Concat(sourceEncoding.GetBytes(text).Select(x => "%" + x.ToString("x2")));` If you paste that long url to chrome, you'll get `http://example.com/hello-world%20%F0%9F%92%9F`

Comment: It is one of the workarounds that I'm trying to avoid to implement but thank you for your time. Also Chrome handles all of them great but I have to use WebClient etc.

Comment: @MatthewCampbell method4

Comment: Sorry, read the post too fast without hitting method 4. Didn't find anything else in the 2.0 dependencies.

Comment: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2016/12/31/using-url-encode-net-core/

Comment: @MatthewCampbell method3

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/UrlEncoder.cs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152398/discussion-between-cilerler-and-matthew-campbell).

Comment: It seems HttpUtility.UrlEncode is available in .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it does, you may find the result as **method3**.  it is a part of **System.Net.WebUtility**